# Register custom URL-scheme in code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-scheme

Is it possible to register a custom URL scheme for an application in code? Or does it have to be done in the plist?

Comment: Interesting idea. Currently you must do it with the plist. Send an [enhancement request](http://bugreporter.apple.com/) (with a good business case) for this feature.

Comment: It can only be done in a plist currently

Comment: @rmaddy In this case I just want my library to have its own modularized, easy configuration. . not sure how many folks will want this, but logged all the same.

Comment: @rmaddy . . Hmmm. . .now that you mention it, I can actually see the ability to dynamically register URL schemes being used in potentially malicious ways. . . I don't think it will fly. . Thanks for your answer.